# Detect malicious GIFs

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, deep-learning, image-classification

I was reading this [article](https://www.inverse.com/article/25505-seizure-tweets-epilepsy-photosensitive-black-mirror) talking about a form of targeted internet bullying which involves sending flashing images via Twitter to people with epilepsy.

I was wondering whether there is a way to detect these malicious GIFs? I first though of it as a classification problem but in reality the content can be anything - what we would need to detect is the flashing lights which have a particular frequency.

Any idea on how to approach this? Which technique can be used?

Answer (score 1):

**GIFs are just a sequence of images**

Given that you just need to find right quantification/pooling of these images to display a GIF. When you displayed a single GIF it will be a collection of different images, where flashing images will have sudden changes in pixel intensity, exactly that is what you want to catch in set of images=GIFs that are malicious.  You just need binary classification from there on.

have a [look at here](https://medium.com/@zan2434/building-a-deep-learning-powered-gif-search-engine-a3eb309d7525)

Comment: interesting approach - so how could we catch the sudden changes in pixel intensity?

Comment: I definitely get the point of splitting the gif into images - however I'm not sure on how to measure intensity change. I could measure distortion levels or white amount for each frame and then average, or count how many times these distortions occur within a second?

Comment: Yes that too. But here is another approach. Lets say you have 3 images=Frames per gif. IF you pool/combine/average these 3, 3-d objects into something 3-d dimensional you can cluster the ones that have sudden changes of white in one cluster, indicating potential flashes of white. (Think in terms of 3 colour windows in one pixel changing their values rapidly, and if it happens for a lot of them its an indicator)

Answer (score 1):

It really seems like a signal processing question first. A rapid google search give : [Automatic detection of epileptogenic video content](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiMjrOQ5L3sAhWNy4UKHbjaCC4QFjABegQIAhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffenix.tecnico.ulisboa.pt%2FdownloadFile%2F844820067124506%2FAutomatic%2520Detection%2520of%2520Epileptogenic%2520Video%2520Content_NR.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1Ihllyl8T68IKMF8ZABKFy). The main work is about signal processing techniques to detect brutal intensity changes in the image. Basically they create a time series that represent the overall difference in intensity between consecutive frames and show that it is usually enough to detect epileptogenic content.

They give an exemple where they are able to measure 4 flashes in less than a second, which is above the 3 flashes per second threshold defined in international recommendations (Recommendation ITU-R BT.1702 Geneva, International Telecommunication Union, 2005) :

[image: Flashes detection]

From other sources, it seems that the flash detection part can be improved (by fourrier analysis to detect spikes, by applying mask to remove low movement part of the images ... etc.). I am not sure the overall process (is this the best way to detect philogenetic content ? is the 3 flash threshold optimal ?) can be significantly improved using ML, as (1) detecting >X spikes in a small time windows seems easy and enough, (2) ML would require a significant collection of videos and (3) it might be quite difficult (and quite unethical) to collect ground truth about epilepsy induction. But this give you a starting point on how to build your feature if you want to go this way.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that you have to do towards a Machine Learning problem is defining the problem.

To solve this question you could either of define what is a Malicious GIF (defining frequency and calculating an appearance ratio... ) or making two datasets, one containing good gifs and the other one malicious gifs. Then you could try to make a machine learning classification problem and then evaluating the results.